# Rails 3.2 selenium web driver testing

Tags: testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, selenium-webdriver

I am using rspec + spork + selenium webdriver to test my app. I don't know how to access my app from selenium(while running rspec) for eg what url should i type in driver.navigate.to to get access to my website?
Best regards 
Artur

Answer (score 0):

You can see what's going on by starting spork this way:

```
SELENIUM='true' spork
```

When you start your tests by:

```
rspec spec --drb
```

Then the browser will open and you can see your test.